# Why UITableView calculate its contentSize based on its default rowheight(44) not custom rowHeight

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

here is the question:

if you have 20 cells and set `tableView.rowHeight = 60`, and after tableView load its data , its `contentSize` is `44*20=880` not `20*60=1200`

what should i do if i want the `contentSize` is `1200`

Comment: Two questions: 1. do you implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`? 2. do you create cell using xib? the `rowHeight` set in xib will override the value you programmatically set.

Comment: 1. not implemented `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` (i try to implement it but not work), i set `tableView.rowHeight` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` . 2. yes, i use nib to create cell but i don't set the `rowHeight` in  this cellClass

Comment: Where you are setting the content size?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should the rowHeight in viewDidLoad() as follows:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 60
```

and then in the cellForRowAtIndex(), write a print statement to confirm the same as follows:

```
print("tableViewContentSize = \(tblView.contentSize)")
```

and you will get the contentSize = 1200, on scrolling the tableView

I hope it will help you!